# "Variable declaration expected" in Nodejs typescript app

Tags: node.js, typescript

Created a method to delete the file in directory.

```
const delete: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void = (dirName, fileName, callback) => {
  fs.unlink(baseDataDir + dirName + "/" + fileName + ".json", (error) => {
    if (!error) {
      callback(false);
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  });
};

const fsHandler: IFSHandler = {
  create,
  read,
  update,
  delete
};

module.exports = fsHandler;
```

Interface defined for `fsHandler`:

```
export interface IFSHandler {
  create: (dirName: string, fileName: string, data: any, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void;
  read: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean, data: any) => void) => void;
  update: (dirName: string, fileName: string, data: any, callback: (error: string | boolean, fileDesc: any) => void) => void;
  delete: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void;
}
```

Typescript Errors:

```
yarn run v1.13.0
$ tsc && node dist/index.js
src/services/fsHandler.ts:69:7 - error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.

69 const delete: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void = (dirName, fileName, callback) => {
         ~~~~~~

src/services/fsHandler.ts:69:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

69 const delete: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void = (dirName, fileName, callback) => {
               ~

src/services/fsHandler.ts:69:104 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

69 const delete: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void = (dirName, fileName, callback) => {
                                                                                                          ~

src/services/fsHandler.ts:84:1 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

84 };
   ~


Found 4 errors.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved keyword you cannot use `delete` for variable name. Change it to something else like `remove` and it will work.

```
const remove: (dirName: string, fileName: string, callback: (error: string | boolean) => void) => void = (dirName, fileName, callback) => {
  fs.unlink(baseDataDir + dirName + "/" + fileName + ".json", (error) => {
    if (!error) {
      callback(false);
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  });
};
```